# CGI perl: Download Script not working

Tags: perl, file, cgi, download

```
print $page->p("Hello All, Downloading file");
my @contents= $ssh->file_content("$dir/$file", 1);
download(@contents, $file);
...
...
...
sub download {
    use strict;
    my @content = shift;
    my $filename = shift;
    print "Content-Type:application/x-download\n";
    print "Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$file\n\n";
    print @content;
    return 1;
}
```

But instead of downloading it, it prints the contents of the file on the screen.
Please tell me where am I wrong?

Comment: What client are you using to test it?

Comment: You mean browser, then its firefox.

Comment: There are clients that aren't browsers. If you were using cURL for example, then I'd expect the output to be printed to screen.

Comment: No its firefox. Tried it on other browsers as well, but same results.

Comment: What does the raw HTTP response look like? Is it what you expect?

Comment: You know that `my @content = shift` will just take the first element of `@contents` and print it, right? It is misleading to use an array there, because it can never hold more than one value.

Comment: How/Where  do I check that? Sorry didnt get it correctly.

Comment: @TLP: but it is printing the whole array and not just first element.

Comment: @tranceporter No, it isn't. `shift` will only remove one element from `@_`, so that's impossible. You will get the exact same result if you change `@content` to `$content`.

Comment: Also, in the sub you are using the variable `$filename`, but printing `$file`.

Comment: @TLP: You were right....it works now. I used $content and now it is showing the save dialog. I'll debug more on this. But really thanks TLP for your help. U r a life saver. :)

Comment: @tranceporter You're welcome. Not sure why that worked, but a good thing nonetheless. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try keeping your headers HTTP compliant:

```
print "Content-Type: application/x-download\r\n";
print "Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$file\r\n\r\n";
print @content;
```